# Rally c# task time spent

Tags: rally

I have a C# .net application using the rally 3.0.1 API. When I query task in my system I get 0.0 for time spent when I know they have time against them. Anyone know how to get this? Below is my code:

```
if (uTasks.Count > 0)
{
  Request taskRequest = new Request(resultChild["Tasks"]);
  QueryResult TaskQueryResult = restApi.Query(taskRequest);
  foreach (var items in TaskQueryResult.Results)
  //foreach (var items in uTasks)
  {
    DataRow dtrow2;
    dtrow2 = dt.NewRow();
    dtrow2["TaskID"]=items["FormattedID"];
    dtrow2["Task Name"] = items["Name"];

    if (items["Owner"] != null)
    {
       var owner = items["Owner"];
       String ownerref = owner["_ref"];
       var ownerFetch = restApi.GetByReference(ownerref, "Name");
       string strTemp = ownerFetch["_refObjectName"];
       dtrow2["Owner"] = strTemp.Replace(",", " ");
     }
     \\else { dtrow2["Owner"] = ""; }
      dtrow2["Task-Est"] = items["Estimate"];
      dtrow2["Task-ToDo"] = items["ToDo"];
      dtrow2["Task-Spent"] = items["TimeSpent"];
      dtrow2["ObjectType"] = "T";
      dt.Rows.Add(dtrow2);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that should work.  You may want to make sure you're including the TimeSpent field in your fetch before issuing the request.

```
taskRequest.Fetch = new List<string>() { "TimeSpent" };
```